# Is there some assistance with AJAX and PHP?

Tags: ajax

I am trying to use AJAX to return high-level calculation results.  However, it appears as though the PHP file that I am pointing the AJAX call to is in the '/' root directory.  Here is a snapshot of how my structure is:  `c:\webserver\test\webroot` (this is the root directory), and then `c:\webserver\test\code` is where the HTML and PHP files are stored - looking to use an AJAX call to point to a PHP file in the non-root folder (which is one folder up, then one folder down).  I tried a few different things, such as '../code' to move up and then over, but that doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing a file location via relative paths *should* work - you'll just need to be sure that you are navigating FROM the correct folder TO the correct folder.

This can be a bit tricky if your javascript file is located in another folder - *if memory serves* you must navigate from the folder containing the javascript file, not from the folder containing the index file.

Alternately, you can use FQDM `http://example.com/folder/folder/file.php` to reference the file. Note that if you are on localhost, you can use a [hosts](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-use-the-hosts-file-to-fake-dns/) file to fake-out the webserver.